# Tense used for giving comments on a place you have been to

Tags: grammar

I'm a bit confused about which tense I should use when, for example, giving feedback on a hotel where I have been staying.

Should I say:

> A) The room *is* clean and well equipped with basic amenities.

or

> B) The room *was* clean and well equipped with basic amenities.

Or, if commenting on the host I met during the stay,
should I say:

> A) The host *is* nice.

or

> B) The host *was* nice.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when it happened, or when you had the room.

Is the room currently clean? Then use **present tense**. If you are giving comments about your hotel room that you rented let's say one month ago, you don't know if it still is clean, therefor you should use past tense, because during your stay it **was** clean.

Comment: It is probably safe to say "The hotel is nice" even though technically it's based on past observation, because the quality of the hotel is a more durable state than the cleanliness of a particular room.